# forcing specific type in a Template class

Tags: c++

Here is my problem:

I have a templatized class

```
Template <class T>
SomeClass
{

    void func1(T* arg1)

    //many methods using T
    void func2(T* arg1);
}
```

For most of the cases, same class type T is passed to class methods and they work on basis of T (so that code can be generic). For some specific cases I want to force func2 to ignore T and use what I want, so can I do something like:

```
void func1(T* arg1)
{

    T* ptr2;
    int* ptr1;
    if (a specific case)
    {
    SomeClass<int>::func2(ptr1);
    }
    else
    {
    func2(ptr2)//so it will assume ptr2 is of type T*
    }
}
```

doesn't seem to work straightaway..

Final working code (for others facing similar issue)

```
#include<stdio.h>
template <class T>
class SomeClass
{
public:
    void func1(T arg1);

    template< typename U >
    void func2(U arg1);
};

template< typename T >
void SomeClass<T>::func1(T arg1)
{
    if (1)
    {
        func2<int>(5); // U will deduce to int
    }
}
template<class T> template<class U> void SomeClass<T>::func2(U arg1)
{
 printf("%d",arg1);
}

int main()
{
    SomeClass<float> c;
    c.func1(5.0);


}
```

Comment: Specialize the template.

Comment: To call `SomeClass<int>::func2`, you need an object of type `SomeClass<int>`, unless `func2` is a static member. Either find a way to create such object, or make `func2` a static member.

Comment: I can't make the function static as it uses some class data structures. Also, I can't overload(specialize) as there is long chain of function calls so I will have to specialize all, looks like there is no easy way out so I will have to look for ways in business logic. Thanks for responses guys !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could work for you:

```
template <class T>
class SomeClass
{
    void func1(T* arg1)

    template< typename U >
    void func2(U* arg1);
};
```

and

```
template< typename T >
void SomeClass<T>::func1(T* arg1)
{
    T* ptr2;
    int* ptr1;
    if (a specific case)
    {
        func2(ptr1); // U will deduce to int
    }
    else
    {
        func2(ptr2); // U will deduce to T
    }
}
```

Comment: great !! this actually worked, note some syntactic changes:

#include<stdio.h>
template <class T>
class SomeClass
{
public:
    void func1(T arg1);

    template< typename U >
    void func2(U arg1);
};

template< typename T >
void SomeClass<T>::func1(T arg1)
{
    if (1)
    {
        func2<int>(5); // U will deduce to int
    }
}
template<class T> template<class U> void SomeClass<T>::func2(U arg1)
{
 printf("%d",arg1);
}

int main()
{
    SomeClass<float> c;
    c.func1(5.0);


}

Comment: I wonder why can't I press enter (newline) in comments, it just submits the post !!
Ok shift enter works but now it did not format the code !!